# Java Scanner while loop

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop, java.util.scanner, system.in

I'm trying to take in a string input which consists of multiple lines of numbers separated by ',' and ';' .

Example:

```
1,2;3,4;5,6;
9,8;7,6;
0,1;
;
```

Code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> alist = new ArrayList<>();
        String delims = ";|\\,";
        int i = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        input.useDelimiter(delims);
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            alist.add(i, input.nextInt());
            System.out.print(i + ' ');
            System.out.print(alist.get(i) + '\n');
            i++;
        }
        System.out.print('x');
```

When I run this in eclipse:

```
1,2;3,4;5,6;    ( <= what i typed in console)
321133123413351436153716    ( <= output)
```

I'd expect something more like:

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5 
5 6
x
```

Why am I getting this sort of output?

Comment: my use of Scanners `hasNext()` method has been when reading files; maybe you need a sentinel-controlled loop. Loop until the user enters -999 or some int that shouldn't be part of the entered data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that `System.in` is basically an infinite stream: `hasNext` will always return true unless the user enters a special command that closes it.

So you need to have the user enter something that tells you they are done. For example:

```
while(input.hasNext()) {
    System.out.print("Enter an integer or 'end' to finish: ");
    String next = input.next();
    if("end".equalsIgnoreCase(next)) {
        break;
    }

    int theInt = Integer.parseInt(next);
    ...
```

For your program, you might have the input you are trying to parse end with a special character like `1,2;3,4;5,6;end` or `1,2;3,4;5,6;#` that you check for.

And on these lines:

```
System.out.print(i + ' ');
System.out.print(alist.get(i) + '\n');
```

It looks like you are trying to perform `String` concatenation but since `char` is a numerical type, it performs addition instead. That is why you get the crazy output. So you need to use `String` instead of `char`:

```
System.out.print(i + " ");
System.out.print(alist.get(i) + "\n");
```

Or just:

```
System.out.println(i + " " + alist.get(i));
```

---

*Edit for comment.*

You could, for example, pull the input using `nextLine` from a `Scanner` with a default delimiter, then create a second `Scanner` to scan the line:

```
Scanner sysIn = new Scanner(System.in);
while(sysIn.hasNextLine()) {
    String nextLine = sysIn.nextLine();
    if(nextLine.isEmpty()) {
        break;
    }

    Scanner lineIn = new Scanner(nextLine);
    lineIn.useDelimiter(";|\\,");

    while(lineIn.hasNextInt()) {
        int nextInt = lineIn.nextInt();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: oh man its always the little things, changing to the double speech completely fixed the output :) thanks

Comment: How would I use the next blank line to end the stream?

Answer (score 0):

Since Radiodef has already answered your actual problem(`"` instead of `'`), here are a few pointers I think could be helpful for you(This is more of a comment than an answer, but too long for an actual comment):

When you use Scanner, try to match the `hasNextX` function call to the `nextX` call. I.e. in your case, use `hasNextInt` and `nextInt`. This makes it much less likely that you will get an exception on unexpected input, while also making it easy to end input by just typing another delimiter.

Scanners `useDelimiter` call returns the Scanner, so it can be chained, as part of the initialisation of the Scanner. I.e. you can just write:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(";|\\,");
```

When you add to the end of an ArrayList, you don't need to(and usually should not) specify the index.

`int i = 0`, `i++` is the textbook example of a for loop. Just because your test statement doesn't involve `i` does not mean you should not use a for loop.

Your code, with the above points addressed becomes as follows:

```
ArrayList<Integer> alist = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(";|\\,");
for (int i = 0; input.hasNextInt(); i++) {
    alist.add(input.nextInt());
    System.out.println(i + " " + alist.get(i));
}
System.out.println('x');
```

Edit: Just had to mention one of my favorite delimiters for Scanner, since it is so suitable here:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\D");
```

This will make a Scanner over just numbers, splitting on anything that is not a number. Combined with `hasNextInt` it also ends input on the first blank line when reading from terminal input.

Comment: *"use hasNextInt [...] making it easy to end input by just typing anything other than a number"* This won't work, actually, the Scanner will just skip the non-int and attempt to scan ahead (it will prompt again) instead of returning false.

Comment: You are right, thanks, I mixed up \\D and his delimiter. Using hasNextInt you have to end input with a delimiter. Updating to correct this.